# How to compare unaligned single bits in two ints?

Tags: c, comparison, bit

To compare the `m`-th bit in `foo` with the `n`-th bit in `bar`, I end up doing something like

```
if ( ( ( foo >> m ) & 1 ) == ( ( bar >> n ) & 1 ) ) {...}
```

or even

```
if ( ! ( ( ( foo >> m ) ^ ( bar >> n ) ) & 1 ) ) {...}
```

but this looks very suboptimal to me. I wonder if there a more straightforward way to do it.

Comment: What `foo` and what `bar`?

Comment: `foo` and `bar` are the two ints.

Comment: And also, what do you want to get, which is lower or higher, or if they are equal or not?

Comment: I don't see any `foo` or `bar` in the snippet posted by you.

Comment: Will m and n be known at compile time?

Comment: I want to know whether they are equal (both ones or both zeroes), or not.

Comment: <Will m and n be known at compile time?> No. The comparison is inside a function, and `m` and `n` depend on the arguments.

Comment: Also, why do you think that those are suboptimal, what do you need it for?

Comment: The first version (with the equality) is far easier to understand than the version with xor and negation; it also has fewer operators in the source code, which might manage to make a difference in the object code (but probably wouldn't).  The first version looks optimal — I don't think you can do it with fewer operations unless you know `n` and/or `m` in advance, which by definition you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me a more readable way is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int foo, bar;
  int foo_bit, bar_bit;
  int foo_mask, bar_mask;

  foo = 60;  // 0b00111100
  bar = 240; // 0b11110000

  foo_bit = 3;
  bar_bit = 5;

  foo_mask = 1 << foo_bit;
  bar_mask = 1 << bar_bit;

  if((foo & foo_mask)>0 == (bar & bar_mask)>0) {
    printf("bit %d in foo and bit %d in bar are equal\n",foo_bit,bar_bit);
  } else {
    printf("bit %d in foo and bit %d in bar are NOT equal\n",foo_bit,bar_bit);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

but it is not "better".

Comment: `(foo & foo_mask) && (bar & bar_mask)` will test if both bits are *set* (both 1), not if both are equal (both 1 or both 0).

Comment: @Dmitri, that's exactly the reason why I asked this question: 0 & 0 gives 0, not 1.

Comment: @Dmitri: thanks, i replaced the `&&` with `==`. that was just a kind of typo :)

Comment: By the way, this code may not work as intended if foo_bit and bar_bit are not equals. In your case, `foo & foo_mask` will return `0b100` while `bar & bar_mask` will return `0b10000` (which is not equal to the former).

Comment: @NiBZ you are absolutely right. i haven't thought about my last comment enough, i am going to fix it asap.

Comment: @NiBZ: now it should work. i test both results for `>0` so if both bits are not set or if both are set the condition is true, no mather wihch bit.

Comment: @Eques: please note that i updatet my answer. now it should behave as excpected.